# Android: How to add Views from a different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to set a blank relativeLayout then start adding some views from another relativeLayout.

I want to do this because at the moment I have many bitmaps in a single layout which causes memory errors. So i want to achieve the effect of adding and removing views as I see fit in the code.

At the moment I am using the `setContentView()` of a layout on the `onCreate()` which causes me to have memory erros since there are too many views to add at once.

Another way. Perhaps it is possible to `setContentView()` of the layout with too many views. Only making it not adding any views before I code it to add specific views.

```
setContentView(R.layout.start_up_screen_denmark);
// This will add all the views in the layout causing a memory error. Making everything below irrelavant. 
// So perhaps there is a way to set the ContentView without adding all the views automaticly. 
// Perhaps i can set a blank layout and add views to that layout from the other layout at will. 

ImageView denmark = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.GoDenmark);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) denmark.getParent();
parent.removeView(denmark);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the Image inside a static View (e.g. ImageView)?

Comment: Im new to the whole memory issue regarding android here. But i read in several posts that if you want to avoid memory leaks then don't set anything to static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a LinearLayout might be better suited for what you're trying to do since you can easily add and remove views from a LinearLayout with `lin_lay.addView(View child, int index)` and `lin_lay.removeViewAt(int index)`.

However, it also sounds like you might want to look into a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) if you have a lot of bitmaps in one layout and it's causing memory issues.

Comment: The problem is not removing or adding a view from the current layout. It is setting the layout without adding all the views at once. Perhaps I misunderstand your intend. Could you give me a code example of what you want to do ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you in the first place. Could you post your code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ah. If the problem is that you are loading too many views at once you definitely want to look into RecyclerView. The RecyclerView only loads the items that are currently on screen and hides the views not in frame until you scroll to see them, making it perfect for lists of memory intensive Views. If RecyclerView isn't what you're looking for and you just want to fix this memory error, please post your error logs

Comment: Will the recyclerView also only add the views whose visibility is set to VISIBLE and remove them again if it is set to INVISIBLE?

Comment: I suggest following the RecyclerView tutorial in the Android docs to get a better understanding about what is added and removed when. You must add and remove your views from a RecyclerViewAdapter